# Download .PDF from VARBINARY(MAX) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, angular, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, restful-url

I can download PDF from my code below, however, "The PDF is corrupted" is mentioned when I tried to open pdf file. What problem is it?

[image]

I am using

```
byte[] binFile = File.ReadAllBytes(file_path_with_filename_with_ext);
```

as SQL parameter which passed through a stored procedure.

C# code

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult DownLoadPdf(int? ID)
{
    string sql = @"SELECT ID, PDFReport
                   FROM [TABLE]";    // which is VARBINARY(MAX) value

    byte[] Report = _dbContext.PDFdto.FromSql(sql).AsNoTracking().Where(r => r.ID == ID.ToString()).Select(r => r.PDFReport).FirstOrDefault();

    return Json(new { Report });
}
```

HTML:

```
$scope.loadPdfClick = function (ID) {
$http({
    url: '@Url.Content("~/Report/DownLoadPdf")',
    method: "GET",
    params: {
        "ID": ID
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    var blob = new Blob([data], { type: "application/pdf" });
    var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
    a.setAttribute('href', objectUrl);
    var filename = "Report_Test.pdf";
    a.setAttribute('download', filename);
    a.click();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    messageAlert("ERROR");
});
```

PS: using .NET Core 1.1 with Angular

Comment: 1. check original file size (= before upload) 2. check size of varbinary in sql server 3. download pdf and compare file size

Comment: @devio original=>2348 bytes , SQL => 2348 bytes, download PDF => 3145 bytes

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but `return Json(new { Report });` sounds like you are saving a JSON document containing a PDF, rather than the PDF itself. Look at the saved file with a text or hex editor to check what is saved. If so, try `new Blob([data.Report])`

Comment: its not work. undefined in data.Report

Comment: Why don't you `return File(Report, "application/pdf", "Report_Test.pdf");` in your `DownLoadPdf` method instead of `return Json(new { Report });`?